# Notification for RingCentral Glip

Tags: push-notification, webhooks, ringcentral, glip

We need the get notifications of new unread messages in Glip. I tried to find this in the API documentation but do not see. Anyone know if that is available?

Comment: please see the updated answer below.

Answer (score 1):

To receive notifications for new messages in Glip, subscribe for webhook or PubNub notifications with the following event filter.

`/restapi/v1.0/glip/posts`

This will send you events for all new posts for your user whiich can be a regular user or a chatbot user. Read more at: https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Team-Messaging-Post-Event

A JavaScript implementation is available in the `glip-client` SDK:

https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-chatbot-js

The [specific lines are at L139-L143](https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-chatbot-js/blob/3913b490ea0732eed869505accc07982fb5a80e3/src/models/Bot.ts#L139-L143).

```js
      await this.rc.post('/restapi/v1.0/subscription', {
        eventFilters: [
          '/restapi/v1.0/glip/posts',
          '/restapi/v1.0/glip/groups',
          '/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~',
        ],
        expiresIn: 473040000, // 15 years
        deliveryMode: {
          transportType: 'WebHook',
          address: process.env.RINGCENTRAL_CHATBOT_SERVER + '/bot/webhook',
        },
      });
```